# Add Border Bottom Width after each menu item?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to achieve a thin line after each menu item in my side Drawer. Where can i write the styling?

```
const mainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Attendance: CheckInOutNavigator,
    Transaction: TransactionNavigator,
    profile: profileNavigator,
    Branch: officeNavigator,
    Report: ReportNavigator,
  },
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Theme.primary,
    },

    contentComponent: (props) => <SideDrawer {...props}></SideDrawer>,
  }
);
```

Side Drawer Component:

```
      <ScrollView style={styles.items}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <Button
          color="red"
          title="Logout"
          onPress={() => {
            dispatch(AuthReducer.logout());
            props.navigation.navigate("signin");
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
```

Comment: In your SideDrawerComponent ?

Comment: yes, its side drawer. it is working, i just want to add a thin line after each menu item.

Comment: add that component to the question

Comment: ```
      <ScrollView style={styles.items}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <Button
          color="red"
          title="Logout"
          onPress={() => {
            dispatch(AuthReducer.logout());
            props.navigation.navigate("signin");
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
```